# Two antennas, one board

Tags: gain

Everybody.

I have a doubt. If I use one connector like this:

https://www.data-alliance.net/rp-sma-t-splitter-y-adapter-joiner-join-2-antenna-cables-to-one-connector/

[image]

In one board and connect two antennas with the same gain and shape at the same time, my gain will improve or I will just mess with everything?

Comment: And both omnidirectional!

Comment: What about the need for impedance matching?

Comment: title reminded me something funny

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where the receiver is located.

The basic thing here is called **constructive or destructive interference**.

If you throw two stones simultaneously into water, you will see an interference pattern of waves.

Some locations will have double wave amplitude (constructive) while others will have no wave amplitude (destructive).

For the antenna case, there will be locations that have a gain of +3dB (double power).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of parts to this problem.

First is the connector you've shown.  Is it really a 50 ohm matched impedance looking into all 3 ports?  If not - if the connector is really just a T-junction conductor in a metal housing, then the mismatch may cancel any gain by having 2 antenna elements.

Second, if the connector really is well matched at all of its ports, then you need to make sure that the cable length (phase length) is the same to each antenna element, assuming to want to maximize the response (gain) broadside to the plane of the 2 elements.  If the paths' phases are different, your 2 element antenna array will have a maximum response away from broadside, and this direction will vary with frequency.

Finally, you need to make sure the two antenna elements are not too close together.  They should be at least half a wavelength apart.  Any closer and you start to lose the benefit of multiple elements.

Finally, as Stefan Wyss said, the very best you can achieve with 2 elements is a 3 dB gain.  And everything else has to be perfect to achieve that.